# Can't right-click on Downloads, Documents, Pictures, Music, Videos in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I can not right-click on Downloads, Documents, Pictures, Music, Videos. When I right-click on them, it opens the menu but I can't click on these menus and it goes to Desktop itself. However, if I run `sfc /scannow` on the command prompt as an administrator and after successfully executing the command I can right-click on them, and also I can click on any menu. But If I shut down the PC and again power on the machine, again the same problem occurs and again I have to execute the command to solve the problem. I can't solve the problem permanently

Answer (score 1):

> However, if I run sfc /scannow on the command prompt as an
> administrator and after successfully executing the command I can
> right-click on them, and also I can click on any menu. But If I shut
> down the PC and again power on the machine, again the same problem
> occurs

That the same problem occurs after restart after running SFC fixed the issue means something deeper has gone wrong.

Run a Windows 10 Repair Install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option in the Repair to Keep Everything and see if that
> works.
>
> The remaining two options are more aggressive:  Keep only Data (this
> keeps data and your user profile but you need to reinstall software)
> and Keep Nothing (which is essentially a Windows reinstall and you
> need to make sure you have backups).